# How to optimize the choice of cointegration coefficient?

Tags: time-series, least-squares, likelihood, cointegration

Testing for cointegration on the linear combination of time series vectors can be done by testing the error term for a unit root. $$Y_t - \gamma X_t = \varepsilon_t$$

In the bivariate case the choice of $\gamma$, the cointegration coefficient, is usually $\hat{\beta}$ as derived from OLS.

However, I noticed that other values for $\gamma$ may produce a series that will test at a higher likelihood of cointegration; i.e., it is possible that choosing $\gamma \neq \hat{\beta} $ minimizes the cointegration test statistic.

**Question:** Can anyone explain why a choice of $\gamma$ that is not derived from OLS in the usual sense may produce a series with a higher likelihood of cointegration?

I find this peculiar, and am curious if it is common practice to seek such a value.

Comment: Do you have some reference or a numerical example for your claim? As OLS has the property of minimizing the sum of squared residuals, one would generally tend to assume that OLS is "best" at making the residual series look stationary? It is also not clear to me if you are still allowed to use the same critical values for the test if you get the residuals with a different $\gamma$. After all, the Engle-Granger c.v.s derive inherently from OLS residuals.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Yes, I found this peculiar myself which is why I posted the question. My reference for this is that I was testing data and realized a lower ADF test statistic when excluding the cointegration coefficient from the calculation of the residual series. Do note that it was a small improvement (i.e. still in the same confidence interval for rejection of the null hypothesis).

Comment: What do you mean by excluding? A reproducible example would really help here

Comment: @ChristophHanck I mean testing $y-x=\epsilon_t$ for unit root as opposed to testing $y-\gamma x=\epsilon_t$ for unit root; i.e., $\gamma = 1$ in the first equation. Exporting the data is not trivial but I will try and get an example together.

Comment: Taking $\gamma$ as given rather than estimating it from the data implies a different null distribution of the test statistic when you are testing for a unit root in $y=\gamma x$ with the ADF test, so you *may* get a lower p-value with prespecified $\gamma$. But I wonder whether you are really able to get a lower ADF test statistic that way...